# How to compare string equality which contains unicode characters in swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In my application I am trying to compare the values coming in from a repo which has number of JSON files, each JSON file will have values for some country as a dictionary for example:

```
{cz: "Doplňky k Apple TV"
 dk: "Apple TVtilbehør" }  //string1 == "Doplňky k Apple TV"
```

Similary I have a local plist which also will have dict for same countries for example :

```
{cz: "Doplňky*k*Apple*TV"
 dk: "*Apple*TV*Tilbehør*" } //string2 == "Doplňky*k*Apple*TV"
```

So, basically I need to compare each country values and then show only differences to the user.

So, in this case `cz` value in JSON file(string1) and local plist(string2) are same except for the fact that string2 has asterisk in it. When I just remove asterisk and compare the strings, they still don't match since `Doplňky k Apple TV` has invisible unicode space after `Apple` in `string1` which looks like a whitespace.

Below is my code to implement the logic:

```
if string2.replaceString(["*", "\u{00a0}"], " ").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == string1.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{00a0}", with: " "){
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: I am trying to remove unicode characters from string2, that is not the way? I do not know how to remove unicodes from string, that could be present anywhere in string2 which is unknown to me.

Comment: Actually I want to exclude only UNICODES, as string2 might contain numbers, currency symbols etc, I want to preserve those things.

Comment: It's rare to see Czech examples here on SO :) Can you describe what are you trying to do, high level description? Is this some user input and you're matching it against your strings? Or any other processing? Asking for context, because _regex match two strings_, _match of the similar strings_, ... is not super clear. You'll need to normalize them probably (different code points can produce the same value, ...), ...

Comment: I'll reframe the question and post in sometime to give more clarity.

Comment: @zrzka edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Doplňky k Apple TV` string looks like that it comes from the Apple website. When I checked it on their website, this string, it contains [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (U+00A0) between `Apple` & `TV`. It's a white space character, but it doesn't equal to a normal [SPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)) (U+0020).

```swift
"Doplňky k Apple\u{00a0}TV" == "Doplňky k Apple TV" // false
```

**First thing to specify - does it matter? Should we treat it as equal or not?**

Then you have `Apple TVtilbehør` & `*Apple*TV*Tilbehør*` strings. Is it intentional typo? Or `Apple TVtilbehør` should be `Apple TV Tilbehør`? Let's assume it's intentional typo to test your comparison.

Next, these `*` (at the beginning/end) in the `*Apple*TV*Tilbehør*` string are ...? **Second thing to specify - should we ignore them? Do they represent a whitespace?**

Next thing is the [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). How would you like to compare these two strings? Swift helps you here ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string#overview)):

> Comparing strings for equality using the equal-to operator (`==`) or a relational operator (like `<` or `>=`) is always performed using Unicode canonical representation. As a result, different representations of a string compare as being equal.

```swift
"Cafe\u{301}" == "Café" // true
```

What about other countries? Like Germany where `Straße` equals to `Strasse`? **Third thing to specify - how we should treat these strings?**

As you can see, there's a lot of things one should think about. Do you have a specification? Follow it. No specification? Your algorithm will stop working sooner or later.

## Playground

I took the liberty to specify all these things by myself:

- All whitespaces do equal
- `*` at the beginning/end doesn't matter (ignored)
- `Straße` does not equal to `Strasse`

Sample code:

```swift
import Foundation

let json = [
    // U+00A0 is NO-BREAK SPACE which looks like a normal space (U+0020)
    "cz": "Doplňky k Apple\u{00a0}TV",
    "dk": "Apple TV Tilbehør",
    "en": "Hello",
    "de": "Straße",
    "fr": "Expos\u{00E9}" // Exposé
]

let plist = [
    "cz": "Doplňky*k*Apple*TV",
    "dk": "*Apple*TV*Tilbehør*",
    "es": "Hola",
    "de": "Strasse",
    "fr": "Expose\u{0301}" // Exposé
]

let jsonKeys = Set(json.keys)
let plistKeys = Set(plist.keys)
let commonKeys = jsonKeys.intersection(plistKeys)
let keysMissingInJson = plistKeys.subtracting(jsonKeys)
let keysMissingInPlist = jsonKeys.subtracting(plistKeys)

print("Languages missing in JSON: \(keysMissingInJson.count)")
keysMissingInJson.forEach { key in
    print(" - \(key)")
}

print("Languages missing in PLIST: \(keysMissingInPlist.count)")
keysMissingInPlist.forEach { key in
    print(" - \(key)")
}

let differentValueKeys: [String] = commonKeys.compactMap { key in
    guard let initialJsonValue = json[key], let initialPlistValue = plist[key] else {
        fatalError("Fix commonKeys")
    }
    
    // Replace all whitespace characters with a normal space
    let jsonValue = String(
        initialJsonValue.map { $0.isWhitespace ? " " : $0 }
    )
    
    let plistValue = initialPlistValue
        // Replace all * with a normal whitespace
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "*", with: " ")
        // Trim all whitespace characters from the beginning/end
        .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    
    return jsonValue == plistValue ? nil : key
}

print("Different values: \(differentValueKeys.count)")
differentValueKeys.forEach { key in
    print(" - \(key): JSON(\(json[key]!)) PLIST(\(plist[key]!))")
}
```

Output:

```
Languages missing in JSON: 1
 - es
Languages missing in PLIST: 1
 - en
Different values: 1
 - de: JSON(Straße) PLIST(Strasse)
```